# Prism CanNavigate not called When I click the Back button

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Let say I have this scenario

A **DataCollectorPage** page that collect data from **multiple** pages via Navigation:

- Initially I'm in the **MainPage**
- I navigate to DataCollectorPage **(relative navigation)**,

Let say I have two pages from which I collect data

- First I navigate to the page1 (**NavigationService.NavigateAsync("page1")**) and get data from there via event (sub/pub) very simple once finished I go back to the previous page DataCollectorPage

-Second, I navigate to the page2 from DataCollectorPage, getting data and go back to DataCollectorPage very **simple scenario**.

How do I **prevent** the user to navigate back (to the **MainPage**) until he save the data collected

Yes I know that I **must implement IConfirmNavigation**, the problem is ( the CanNavigate) **never** be called when click the back buttton whilst CanNavigate it is called each time I navigation to page1 or page2.

**Question: why CanNavigate is Called when navigating forward but not called when navigating backward?!**

Can anyone help!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Prism are you using? Also can you try updating to IConfirmNavigationAsync.

Comment: @DanS. Brian message me via twitter and said that is unsupported by design, I found a workaround https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/ , it works for me, what do you think about it? is there another solution for this pb, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DanS.sorry, I use Prism v 6.3.0.0

Comment: the solution I found in the link above not working for android, Overriding both the `OnOptionsItemSelected` and `OnBackPressed` in the MainActivity isn't working, the breakpoints aren't even hit. :( can anyone help